# python extract date and hour value from dict object in array

Tags: python, arrays, date, extract, hour

I want to extract date and hour value (e.g. 2013-10-04 11, 2013-10-04 04, 2013-10-04 03 etc). When I use keys(), then I am able to get 2013-10-04 not hour and when using items(), then all data extracted. If you know the way to extract date and hour value, please let me know. Additionally, the data has 30 min intervals.

```
u'Station_paris_2013-10-04': {'2013-10-04 11:00:00': array([ number,   number,   number, ...,
        number, number, number]), '2013-10-04 04:00:00': array([ number,   number, number, ...,
         number, number, number]), '2013-10-04 03:00:00': array([ number, number, number, ...,
        number, number, number]), '2013-10-04 14:30:00': array([ number, number, number, ...,
        number, number, number]), '2013-10-04 20:00:00': array([ number, ....]...)
```

Sorry for confusing..

This is the code for `export_allcorr2`  and use the `allcorr[ccfid]` as data.

```
 def export_allcorr2(session, ccfid, data):
        output_folder = get_config(session, 'output_folder')
        station1, station2, components, filterid, date = ccfid.split('_')
    
        path = os.path.join(output_folder, "%02i" % int(filterid),
                            station1, station2, components)
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
    df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data).T
    df.columns = get_t_axis(session)
    df.to_hdf(os.path.join(path, date+'.h5'), 'data')
    del df
    return



if params.keep_all:
   for ccfid in allcorr.keys():
       export_allcorr2(db, ccfid, allcorr[ccfid])
```

This is a part of the file (`allcorr`) for one station pair that I am using,

```
'2013-10-27 10:30:00': array([ 583.55720165,  424.74395062,  244.40351166, ...,  244.40364883,
        424.74411523,  583.55747599]), '2013-10-27 16:30:00': array([ 199.66430727,   18.39147977, -157.45584362, ..., -157.45602195,
         18.39139403,  199.66432099]), '2013-10-27 16:00:00': array([ -97.27305213, -365.27786008, -621.36060357, ..., -621.36076818,
       -365.27802469,  -97.27297668]), '2013-10-27 21:30:00': array([-436.08005487, -389.74776406, -327.61319616, ..., -327.61300412,
       -389.74773663, -436.07994513]), '2013-10-27 11:00:00': array([-649.70282579, -597.36164609, -523.04197531, ..., -523.04170096,
       -597.36131687, -649.70266118]), '2013-10-27 20:30:00': array([ 347.37681756,  218.49106996,   88.03422497, ...,   88.03427298,
        218.49113855,  347.37687243]), '2013-10-27 12:30:00': array([  34.91324417,  -93.73432099,  171.31466392, ...,  171.31396433,
        -93.73384088,   34.91361454]), '2013-10-27 13:30:00': array([-289.4951989 , -404.48175583, -501.02052126, ..., -501.02046639,
       -404.48170096, -289.49500686]), '2013-10-27 07:30:00': array([-108.69506859,  -44.65974623,    7.96771948, ...,    7.96728738,
        -44.65979424, -108.69509602]), '2013-10-27 09:30:00': array([-630.18035665, -614.95835391, -597.89119342, ..., -597.89113855,
       -614.95807956, -630.18024691]), '2013-10-27 17:00:00': array([-276.81805213, -267.21061728, -246.72584362, ..., -246.72556927,
       -267.21053498, -276.81794239]),
```

`ccfid` shows `u'05.SS08_05.SS09_ZZ_01_2013-11-06'` which is 'Net.Sta_Net.Sta_component_ccfid_date'. But what I want is date with hour.

This is `allcorr[ccfid]`.

```
 {'2013-11-07 07:30:00': array([  2.01912938e-08,  -5.87221879e-08,   7.99213765e-08, ...,
     9.93437383e-08,   4.46988525e-08,  -4.40811423e-08]), '2013-11-07 14:30:00': array([ -7.76317889e-09,   1.72162791e-09,   1.76833389e-08, ...,
    -4.17227052e-08,  -8.08114523e-09,   7.22184605e-09]), '2013-11-07 00:00:00': array([ -1.67720752e-08,  -4.86950919e-08,  -3.92029027e-08, ...,
    -4.25311992e-08,  -1.43883637e-08,  -1.86576377e-08]), '2013-11-07 16:00:00': array([ -1.54196405e-08,  -6.50798506e-08,  -3.71392759e-08, ...,
    -3.63095301e-08,   4.17709433e-10,  -1.11803857e-07]), '2013-11-07 15:30:00': array([ -4.30306800e-08,  -8.02815645e-08,   1.83716952e-08, ...,
    -3.71510132e-08,  -5.32969688e-08,   5.72185107e-08])
```

And in the `export_allcorr2`code, what I want is to make the data file format from Y-M-D to Y-M-D-H or Y-M-D H format. So extract the H (hour) data, and join the files of same station pair, date, and hour.

I want organizing arrays data in the same hour in one place, also 16:00:00 and 16:30:00 will be in the same place.

Originally, the date files were extracted as a 'date.h5' format (e.g. 2013-10-14.h5) in keep_all code. Additionally, in the '2013-10-14.h5', there are 2013-10-14 00:00:00, 2013-10-14 00:30:00, 2013-10-14 01:00:00, etc.

So as a same format, I want to extract hour as one file (e.g. 2013-10-14_01.h5, 2013-10-14_02.h5) and in '2013-10-14_01.h5' file, there will be 2013-10-14_01:00 and 2013-10-14_01:30.

Therefore, what I want in the codes is to know the keyword (related to allcorr in the keep_all code) to extract date and hour and replace daily format to hourly format.

Edited..

```
    if params.keep_all:
    for ccfid in allcorr.keys():
        final_data={}
        for data_key in allcorr[ccfid]:
            print('NET,STA,NET,STA,COMP,FILTERID,DATE', ccfid)
            temp_date=dt.datetime.fromisoformat(data_key)
            hh=temp_date.strftime('%H')
            dh=temp_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
            dm=temp_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            data=allcorr[ccfid][data_key]
            print('DATE AND HOUR', dh)
            print('DATA_KEY', data_key)
            print('ONLY HOUR',hh)
            print('DATA RELATED TO THE DATE AND HOUR', allcorr[ccfid][data_key])
            container = final_data.get(dh, False)
            if not container:
                container = []
                final_data[dh] = container
            container.extend(allcorr[ccfid][data_key])
            print('THE LENGTH OF DATA', len(container))
            export_allcorr2(db, ccfid, hh, container)
```

When I do not contain the 'container' part in the code, 30 min data overwrite on the 00 min data. So I run the code with the container part. The result..

```
NET,STA,NET,STA,COMP,FILTERID,DATE 05.SS01_05.SS01_ZZ_01_2013-10-08
    DATE AND HOUR 2013-10-08 00
    DATA_KEY 2013-10-08 00:00:00
    ONLY HOUR 00
    DATA RELATED TO THE DATE AND HOUR [ 9268.65717062  8616.97848119  7872.42382341 ...,  7872.42115785
      8616.97759267  9268.6562821 ]
    THE LENGTH OF DATA 4801
    NET,STA,NET,STA,COMP,FILTERID,DATE 05.SS01_05.SS01_ZZ_01_2013-10-08
    DATE AND HOUR 2013-10-08 00
    DATA_KEY 2013-10-08 00:30:00
    ONLY HOUR 00
    DATA RELATED TO THE DATE AND HOUR [  375.50442871 -1328.53555463 -3054.59036513 ..., -3054.58703318
     -1328.53966403   375.50603915]
    THE LENGTH OF DATA 9602
```

And the error..

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9602 elements, new values have 4801 elements
```

Comment: you may want to include your exact expected outcome given your input here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime` to extract day, hour etc.

```
inp = {'2013-10-04 11:00:00':["rand_stuff"],
      '2013-10-04 04:00:00':["rand_stuff"]}
from datetime import datetime
for ts in inp.keys():
    dt = datetime.strptime(ts,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"Date: {dt} Hour: {dt.hour} Day: {dt.day}") 


Date: 2013-10-04 11:00:00 Hour: 11 Day: 4
Date: 2013-10-04 04:00:00 Hour: 4 Day: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
import datetime as dt
import random as rnd

def fake_data():
    temp = (rnd.random() * rnd.randint(10, 100)) * (-1 * rnd.choice([-1, 1]))

    return round(temp, 6)

_max = 10

# creating some test data 
sample = {
    '2013-10-27 10:30:00' : [fake_data() for x in range(_max)],
    '2013-10-27 16:00:00' : [fake_data() for x in range(_max)],
    '2013-10-27 16:30:00' : [fake_data() for x in range(_max)],
    '2013-10-27 11:00:00' : [fake_data() for x in range(_max)],
    '2013-10-27 20:30:00' : [fake_data() for x in range(_max)],
    
    }


def printer(data):

    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)
        print("-------------------")


def main():

    final_data = {}


    for data_key in sample:

        # create date from key 
        temp_date = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(data_key)

        # extract only time data
        temp_time = temp_date.time()

        # if this hour is in our records
        container = final_data.get(temp_time.hour, False)

        # if not in the recors then record it
        if not container:
            
            container = []
            
            # key can be string as well if you like
            final_data[temp_time.hour] = container

        # add the data the hours record
        container.extend(sample[data_key])

    printer(final_data)

main()
```

I put everything simple with comments, if something is confusing or anything else comment and I will edit or answer. Good luck!

Comment: I edited.  Sorry for the less details.

Comment: For being certain , do you want only hour data from the dict data or you want organize arrays data in the same hour in one place, I can extract the hour but in this case  something like 16:00:00 nad 16:30:00 will be in same place? Please add your desired output. Thank you!

Comment: I added answers at the lowest part in the question! If there are more information, please let me know.

Comment: I appreciate your help. May I ask one more question?

I succeed to make 'date_hour.h5'file format and extract related hour data. However, when I run the code, there is an error of 'ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9602 elements, new values have 4801 elements'. Even though I print the length of the container after extend, it shows 9602 but nothing changed.

Comment: I added the code and results with error on the post. The error occurs at the export_allcorr2 part.

Comment: @Susan, the error is from `export_allcor2` functions, and I cannot get its goal well? Check the function logic then comment its goal below my solution I will find a way! And tell me if the dict date and hour solution work well or Not!

Comment: The goal of the function is to make directory  and save data as hdf format. In the function, above 'df' part is for making directories to save data. Below 'df' part is for gather data and save it as hdf format. I think the problem occurs when save data due to the length. I will try to solve it again. And as comment above, the dict date and hour solution works so well. Thank you so much for your help!